# How to make many plots with multiply groupby pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Sorry, I can't google how to get my aim so I am here.

see some sandbox datatable:

```
   mode  X   Y
0     1  3  10
1     1  4  11
2     1  3  12
3     1  4  13
4     2  3  14
5     2  4  15
6     2  3  16
7     2  4  17
```

I created following sandbox code. So here, I want plot with TWO lines corresponding to the two different modes ('mode 1' and 'mode 2'). X-axis should be 3,4. And here I want to get two lines `(3,(10+12)/2)--(4,(11+13)/2)` for mode 1 with averaged Y and analogical `(3,15)--(4,16)` for mode 2.

But this code even doesn't work.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2],[3,4,3,4,3,4,3,4],list(range(10,18))]).T
df.columns = ['mode','X','Y']

mode = df.groupby(['mode'])['mode'].mean()
Ox =  df.groupby(['X'])['X'].mean()
Oy =  df.groupby(['mode','X'])['Y'].mean()

for x in mode:
    plt.plot(Ox, Oy[Oy['mode'== x]] , label = 'test' + x)

plt.savefig('testpandas.pdf')
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try the [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/) package, which has a lot of functionality for stuff like this

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.lmplot(data=df,hue='mode',x='X',y='Y',x_estimator=np.mean)
```

Here's one way to do it in plain pandas:

```
y_means=df.groupby(['mode','X'],as_index=False).mean()
for mode,g in y_means.groupby('mode'):
    plt.plot(g['X'],g['Y'],'o-',label = 'mode = ' + str(mode))
```

Comment: sorry, but I've found my own solution... You are a litte late :) 
but I appreciate your help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

***It's an answer of asking person.***

Actually I've found solution by myself.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2],[3,4,3,4,3,4,3,4],list(range(10,18))]).T
df.columns = ['mode','X','Y']

mode = df.groupby(['mode'])['mode'].mean()
Ox =  df.groupby(['X'])['X'].mean()
Oy =  df.groupby(['mode','X'])['Y'].mean()

for x in mode:
    plt.plot(Ox, Oy[mode[x]] , label = 'test' + str(x))

plt.savefig('testpandas.png')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would guess the easiest way to do this is to use a  `pivot_table`. This reduces the whole thing to two lines:

```
piv = pd.pivot_table(df, columns="mode", index="X")
plt.plot(piv)
```

or even only one, if you use pandas integrated plotting functionality:

```
pd.pivot_table(df, columns="mode", index="X").plot()
```

---

The complete solution using matplotlib:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2],[3,4,3,4,3,4,3,4],list(range(10,18))]).T
df.columns = ['mode','X','Y']

piv = pd.pivot_table(df, columns="mode", index="X")
print piv

plt.plot(piv)

plt.legend(labels=["mode {}".format(c[1]) for c in piv.columns.values])
plt.show()
```

which prints the pivot table as

```
       Y    
mode   1   2
X           
3     11  15
4     12  16
```

and creates the plot

[image]

Comment: Instead of commenting "looks nice" you may simply upvote.